# Asynchrone respond in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm working in typescript to make a query to a server and get a response from it.

Here is my code :

```
allDialogUser(objet): Promise<string> {
    var dialogs;
    this.http.post(this.serverAddress + this.chat + this.alldialoguser, objet)
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            dialogs = data.dialogs;
            return dialogs;
        });
}
```

and

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.mesConversations = await this.api.allDialogUser({"id_offre":1, "is_offre":false}); // A MODIFIER
}
```

I know **allDialogUser** receives the response, the problem is that **ngOnInit** doesn't seem the be waiting for the response and mesConversations attribute is undefined.

Comment: Does this even compile? 
Since if I align the brackets `allDialogUser` isn't returning anything, as `return dialogs;` is contained within the arrow-function.
You probably wanted to await the result of your `http.post`-promise to return the result of your `then`-function.

Comment: you mean I should put the **return dialogs;**  ? I tried but it still doesn't wait for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allDialogUser` wasn't returning a promise, so there was nothing to `await` for.
You can simply return the created promise.

```
function allDialogUser(objet): Promise<string> {
    return this.http.post(this.serverAddress + this.chat + this.alldialoguser, objet)
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => data.dialogs);
}

async function ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.mesConversations = await this.api.allDialogUser({"id_offre":1, "is_offre":false});
}
```

I've created a very simple proof of concept in the Typescript-Playground: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20allDialogUser()%3A%20Promise%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20resolve(%22test%22)%20%7D%2C%201000)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20ngOnInit()%3A%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(await%20allDialogUser())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AngOnInit()%3B).

But you'd most likely benefit from reading up on promisses:

- [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?